# How can I use the rotation gesture handler to rotate an animated view in react native about a specific point (not its center)?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, react-native, expo

I have used the below model to make a handler rotate but cannot find a way to manipulate it as to make the handle rotate from where it begins instead of its center. As well, I am struggling to make the rotation occur with only one finger instead of two.

I think maybe the answer lies in the withAnchorPoint library but I’m not sure of how to apply it.

Requiring assistance

```
import React from 'react';
import {Animated, StatusBar, Image, ImageBackground, Dimensions, StyleSheet, View, Text} from "react-native";
import { PanGestureHandler, PinchGestureHandler, State, RotationGestureHandler } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
//import { withAnchorPoint } from 'react-native-anchor-point';

import { USE_NATIVE_DRIVER } from '../../config';


const {width} = Dimensions.get('screen');
const SIZE = width * .9;

export default class MovableClock extends React.Component {
    panRef = React.createRef();
    rotationRef = React.createRef();
    pinchRef = React.createRef();
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    /* Pinching */
    this._baseScale = new Animated.Value(1);
    this._pinchScale = new Animated.Value(1);
    this._scale = Animated.multiply(this._baseScale, this._pinchScale);
    this._lastScale = 1;
    this._onPinchGestureEvent = Animated.event(
      [{ nativeEvent: { scale: this._pinchScale } }],
      { useNativeDriver: USE_NATIVE_DRIVER }
    ); 

    /* Rotation */
    this._rotate = new Animated.Value(0);
    this._rotateStr = this._rotate.interpolate({
      inputRange: [-100, 100],
      outputRange: ['-100rad', '100rad'],
    });
    this._lastRotate = 0;
    this._onRotateGestureEvent = Animated.event(
      [{ nativeEvent: { rotation: this._rotate } }],
      { useNativeDriver: USE_NATIVE_DRIVER }
    );

    /* Tilt */
    this._tilt = new Animated.Value(0);
    this._tiltStr = this._tilt.interpolate({
      inputRange: [-501, -500, 0, 1],
      outputRange: ['1rad', '1rad', '0rad', '0rad'],
    });
    this._lastTilt = 0;
    this._onTiltGestureEvent = Animated.event(
      [{ nativeEvent: { translationY: this._tilt } }],
      { useNativeDriver: USE_NATIVE_DRIVER }
    );
  }

  _onRotateHandlerStateChange = event => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
      this._lastRotate += event.nativeEvent.rotation;
      this._rotate.setOffset(this._lastRotate);
      this._rotate.setValue(0);
    }
  };
  _onPinchHandlerStateChange = event => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
      this._lastScale *= event.nativeEvent.scale;
      this._baseScale.setValue(this._lastScale);
      this._pinchScale.setValue(1);
    }
  };
  _onTiltGestureStateChange = event => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
      this._lastTilt += event.nativeEvent.translationY;
      this._tilt.setOffset(this._lastTilt);
      this._tilt.setValue(0);
    }
  };



    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.background}>
                <StatusBar hidden={true}/>
                <View style={[styles.bigQuadran]}>
                </View>
                <Image style={styles.numbers}
                source={require("../assets/nobgfreeclock2.png")}/>
                <View style={[styles.mediumQuadran]}/>
                <PanGestureHandler
                ref={this.panRef}
                onGestureEvent={this._onTiltGestureEvent}
                onHandlerStateChange={this._onTiltGestureStateChange}
                minDist={10}
                minPointers={2}
                maxPointers={2}
                avgTouches>
                    <Animated.View style={[styles.mover 
                    //{transform: [{ translateX: this.translateX, }, { translateY: this.translateY}]}
                    ]}>
                        <RotationGestureHandler
                            ref={this.rotationRef}
                            simultaneousHandlers={this.pinchRef}
                            onGestureEvent={this._onRotateGestureEvent}
                            onHandlerStateChange={this._onRotateHandlerStateChange}
                            >
                                <Animated.View style={[styles.mover]}>
                                    <PinchGestureHandler
                                    ref={this.pinchRef}
                                    simultaneousHandlers={this.rotationRef}
                                    onGestureEvent={this._onPinchGestureEvent}
                                    onHandlerStateChange={this._onPinchHandlerStateChange}
                                    >
                                        <Animated.View style={[styles.hours, 
                                        {transform: [
                                            { perspective: 200 },
                                            { scale: this._scale },
                                            { rotate: this._rotateStr },
                                            { rotateX: this._tiltStr },
                                        ]},
                                        ]}/>
                                    </PinchGestureHandler>
                                </Animated.View> 
                        </RotationGestureHandler>
                    </Animated.View>
                </PanGestureHandler>
                    
                {/*
                <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={this.onPanGestureEvent}>
                    <Animated.View style={[styles.mover, {
                        transform: [{ translateX: this.translateX, }, { translateY: this.translateY}]}]}>
                        <View style={styles.minutes}/>
                    </Animated.View>
                </PanGestureHandler>
                
                <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={this.onPanGestureEvent}>
                    <Animated.View style={[styles.mover, {
                        transform: [{ translateX: this.translateX, }, { translateY: this.translateY}]}]}>
                        <View style={styles.seconds}/>
                    </Animated.View>
                </PanGestureHandler>
                    */}
                <View style={[styles.smallQuadran]}/>
            </View>

        );
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'whitesmoke',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
      background: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
      },
      mover: {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: SIZE,
        height: SIZE,
        borderRadius: SIZE/2,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        top: 68
      },
      hours: {
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        height: '20%',
        marginTop: '30%',
        width: 4.5,
        borderRadius: 4.5
      },
      minutes: {
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        height: '35%',
        marginTop: '15%',
        width: 3.5,
        borderRadius: 3.5
      },
      seconds: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(227, 71, 134, 1)',
        height: '35%',
        marginTop: '15%',
        width: 2,
        borderRadius: 2
      },
      bigQuadran: {
        width: SIZE * 0.815,
        height: SIZE * 0.815,
        borderRadius: SIZE * 0.40,
        backgroundColor: 'ghostwhite',
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: SIZE * 0.030,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 100
      },
      smallQuadran: {
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        borderRadius: 5,
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(227, 71, 134, 1)',
        top: 250
      },
      
      numbers: {
        width: SIZE * 0.78,
        height: SIZE * 0.78,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 107,
        borderRadius: SIZE * 4
      }

})
```